# How to correctly setup homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I own a Mac M1 with Monterey 12.3.1. I often experience problems uninstalling brew packages. Here an example:

I installed `pnpm` with homebrew. Then, I tried to uninstall it:

```
brew uninstall pnpm
```

If I `brew uninstall pnpm`, the following message appears:

```
Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pnpm
```

Still, pnpm is installed:

```
$> which pnpm                                           
/opt/homebrew/bin/pnpm
```

So, it seems that homebrew is looking up at Cellar while the package is at `/opt/homebrew/bin`.  I don't get the concept of Cellar.  Is it a homebrew configuration problem?

How to fix homebrew to uninstall correctly?

Comment: Cellar is where all Homebrew packages get installed, there are only symlinks in bin. Did you install pnpm via Homebrew at all? Is /opt/homebrew/bin/pnpm a symlink and where does it point to?

Comment: Have you tried `brew uninstall pnpm --force`? This may cause it to uninstall the files, even if it thinks they aren't there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
corepack enable && corepack prepare pnpm@latest --activate
```

As per [Corepack docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/corepack.html#enabling-the-feature) & [pnpm docs](https://pnpm.io/installation#using-corepack).

This won't uninstall Homebrew's `pnpm`, but it will effectively replace it with Corepack's version.

I had the same issue, but only when using node v18 (via [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#readme)). (I had already run `corepack enable` in node v16)

With node v16:

```sh
% which pnpm
~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/pnpm
```

With node v18:

```sh
% which pnpm
/opt/homebrew/bin/pnpm
```

`/opt/homebrew/bin/pnpm` links to `/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/pnpm/bin/pnpm.cjs`.

Still not sure why it's there, I thought maybe from a `brew install node`, but `brew uninstall node` + `brew autoremove` didn't get rid of it. At any rate, I'm happy just to be back to using Corepack's `pnpm`.

PS: [`brew leaves`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#leaves---installed-on-request---installed-as-dependency) will "list installed formulae that are not dependencies of another installed formula", it only really makes sense to `brew uninstall` those formulae, as others are just dependencies.